# Facebook login session with a second login

Tags: php, android, facebook, session

I'm developing an android app that performs a two-stages login.

First the user logs in using a Facebook account, and then he logs in a party giving party name and party password which are stored in our server's database.  The log-in with Facebook is handled by integrating the Facebook API both in android and in our server, so when a user logs in using Facebook, a Facebook session starts.

I would like to know what's the best way to integrate the party login knowing that the party will be linked to the user.

I have some ideas like creating a PHP session associated with the Facebook session and adding the variable party to the session, or directly using the database to associate a party to a user. I want to be able to make requests using the access token given by Facebook.

In conclusion, the server has to know the user and the party in which he is participating just by receiving the access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the party name and password are already stored in your database, then you should just store the user association to a party as well.

So one way of many

- Store a table with all the party names, party ID and passwords
- Store a table with the users, user ID and access tokens
- Store a table that matches a party ID to a user ID

So then when you look up a user by access token

- you query for a the ID associated with that access token
- you do a query on your database to look up all PIDs (party ID) associated with that user ID

Of course based on your scale and the actual final schema you are looking at you will need to change this around.

Try to write out a flowchart to see how it will show. For example this is a flowchart showing two logins, email and Facebook.

[image: Facebook Registration Flow]

Comment: If i wanted a party to autodestroy after some given time, isn't it better to store the relation that matches partyID to userID in a PHP session?

Comment: However you wish there are many ways to approach this. As I said since you are already storing the party you will need to query the database for the party anyway. So if you do auto destroy wouldn't you not destroy the associated party name and password in your database?